# Glide: don't pause thumbnail requests

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm trying to implement "lazy" image loading in RecyclerView. Meaning that only thumb images are shown until the user stops scrolling. I'm using RecyclerView scroll listener to call `glide.resumeRequests()` and `glide.pauseRequests()` at specific times.

Problem is that, when I call `glide.pauseRequests()` thumbnail requests are also paused. 
I want to pause/resume only full image loading. Couldn't find a way to separate those two request types.

The final goal is that user sees thumbnails immediately ( or fastly ) and then full images will replace them. At this moment, user sees nothing until scrolling is stopped